# how to hide resume from selected employer

Tags: plugins

I am working on WordPress wp-job-manager-resumes and wp-job-manager and under Candidate Dashboard I have to give the option for candidate to Hide resume from the selected Company.

That is if the Candidate selected Company X then X will not be able to view Candidate Resume.

Any suggestion on How I can complete this task.

Below is what I am thinking to implement:

> Will create a multiselect dropodown Company names and on the search resume page and resume page will check for the selected company. If match found then resume will be hidden.
>
> I should also create a separate table in mysql which stores the blocked companies by candidate

Any suggestion on how to do this.

Edits:

I am storing the candidate excluded company list in user meta with below code

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     $user_id=$current_user->ID;
    $meta_value[]= $_POST['exclude_company_from_search'];
    $meta_key="exclude_from_employer_search";
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
```

Now I not able to filter it in search resume page.

Here is full code of saving company to be excluded using short code in my functions.php.

```
  <?php
function custom_shortcode() {
    if(isset($_POST['exclude_company'])){
         $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
         $user_id=$current_user->ID;
        $meta_value[]= $_POST['exclude_company_from_search'];

        $merged = array_reduce($meta_value, 'array_merge', array());
        $comma_separated_meta_value = implode(',', $merged);




        $meta_key="exclude_from_employer_search";
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $comma_separated_meta_value );

    }
     wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-job-manager-multiselect' );
    global $wpdb;


$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->users.ID, $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value FROM $wpdb->users INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta ON ( $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_company_name') ORDER BY user_login ASC" );
     ?>
     <form method="post" action="" name="ec" id="ec">
     <select multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="" name="exclude_company_from_search[]" id="exclude_company_from_search" class="job-manager-multiselect" data-no_results_text="No results match" data-multiple_text="Select Companies to Exclude">
    <?php foreach ( $results as $value ) :?>


        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value->ID ); ?>" <?php if ( ! empty( $value->meta_value ) && is_array( $value->meta_value) ) selected( in_array( $key, $value->meta_value ), true ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $value->meta_value ); ?></option>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="exclude_company" id="exclude_company" value="Exclude Company" />
</form>
<?php
}
add_shortcode( 'exclude_company_list', 'custom_shortcode' );
?>
```

I am unable to filter it in search resume page.

Comment: This option( to hide the resume) is only for one company or the user can select multiple companies? Also How you choose to show the list of Companies? Do you filter somehow or just show all the companies your site supports? This can be a problem down the road.

Comment: Candidate can select N number of companies. Will show the list of Companies registered with us. And under candidate dashboard, he can select any company for the EXCLUDE LIST

Comment: The trick part is how you gonna filter the candidates and hides the ones choose to hide it. How you show the candidates resumes? You use filters like taxonomies? Tags custom filters?

Comment: Yeah!. But I am thinking to create a function that return true or false. Definitely employer will be logged in to search. After this I am blank and still thinking....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make some assumptions:

- Not using custom table
- All resumes are with a post type of resume
- You are comfortable with some sql

> ```
>  SELECT * FROM wp_posts wp  WHERE wp.post_type = 'resume' AND
>  wp.post_author NOT IN (  SELECT distinct wu.umeta_id FROM wp_usermeta
>  wu    WHERE wu.meta_key='exclude_from_search' AND
>  wu.meta_value='the_company_id'
> );
> ```

The basic idea is to first get all the ids of users don't want to show the resumes for a particular company. After that is straight on to select depending of you filtering process.

The reason why I din't use a custom table is because of the power of the meta fields that can support multiple **values(entries)** for the same **meta_key** and **user_id**. This can help you **keep track** of all the user preferences depending on the hidden of resumes.

Comment: Nice, I am storing the exclude company list in user meta table serialized way. So here I have candidate Id as User_Id and meta_key and meta_value as serialized array. I am now in trouble to filter this in resume search. I am stucked on how to filter in wp_resume_manager_functions.php

Comment: Please see my question again. I have edited.

Comment: Never store something you want to use in searches/filters as a serialized value. WP does allow for multiple post meta fields with the same name, and that allows you to use SQL for queries, while you'll have to unserialize every row and do it in PHP if you store it as a serialized value.

Comment: Ok janh. Now saving it as comma separated using implode.